# Can Spring Boot async methods meet at one point?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Imagine I have two async methods and a main method. In the main method, one is called in line of code 1 and another in line of code 2. I want the code to be blocked in line of code 3 because I need the results of those 2 methods.

Is this possible in Spring Boot? What could I use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use completableFuture.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture#Multiple

CompletableFuture.allOf() or CompletableFuture.join() ll help;